# plotting points on a map over time ,where the transparency of the point is based on a value in the dataframe in R

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, maps, shapefile

```
Long    |Lat    |Year   |Cases  
-2.12345|51.456 |1      |2
-2.12345|51.456 |2      |4
-2.12345|51.456 |3      |1
-2.5678 |51.656 |1      |0
-2.5678 |51.656 |2      |5
-2.5678 |51.656 |3      |9
-2.7654 |51.945 |1      |8
-2.7654 |51.945 |2      |5
-2.7654 |51.945 |3      |6
```

I can plot the long and lat on a GAD map.

```
library(sp)
gadmuk <- readRDS(file.choose())
library(rgeos)
uksimpl <- gSimplify(gadmuk, tol = 0.03)
plot(uksimpl)
plot(uksimpl, col = 'lightgrey', border = 'darkgrey', xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(50, 59))
points(x = df$lon, y = df$lat, col = 4, pch = 18)
```

I want to plot the long and lat where the transparency of the dots change depending on the number in the cases col. and to do this overtime. So all the year 1 are plotted first (they all have the same long and lat) and then all the year 2 and all the year 3.

I have tried writing it in to loop for i in 3  and using ggplot

```
map <- uksimpl + geom_point(data = df, 
                            aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, alpha = df$case), 
                            size=5, col=4)
```

I wonder about using animation and shapefiles rather than GGplot?

Comment: This feels like you're using a map "cuz maps are cool". This data seems like it would be more respected in a non-geo vis.

Comment: @hrbrmstr unfortunately in this circumstance i need a map. this is only an example for large DF. But i take note of your point.